# Function overwrite

Tags: function, google-sheets, fivem, rosters

I have a google sheet that uses this formula to organize my roster into groups,

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL","Ranks!A:O") , MATCH(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL","Ranks!D:D") , {"Civilian Manager", "Civilian Supervisor", "Trusted Civilian", "Civilian III", "Civilian II", "Civilian I", "Probationary"}, 0) = MATCH(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_URL","Ranks!Q1") , {"Civilian Manager", "Civilian Supervisor", "Trusted Civilian", "Civilian III", "Civilian II", "Civilian I", "Probationary"}, 0))
```

This works however, when I have data in the cells it is using it gives me an error. I would just like to overwrite the cells instead of it giving the error.

Comment: Formula can't overwrite any values to cells. You have to keep clear cells so that formula can spill results.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that explains the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way